# What does "compass" mean as a verb?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "compass" mean as a verb here? What would you replace it with? Neither "go around", nor "surround", nor "contrive to accomplish" (the verb meanings as per Lexico) seem to do. As for "the downfall of my father's grey hairs", I take it it means "the death of my father". The passage's from Wells's Invisible Man

> I was apathetic, and I tried in vain to recover the enthusiasm of my first inquiries, the passion of discovery that had enabled me to **compass** even the downfall of my father's grey hairs

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the dictionary meant it in a literal way: "Go around (something) in a circular course"

Comment: What about ["encompass"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compass), which means roughly "to understand" or "comprehend"?

Comment: @stangdon well, it's not what's written

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I mean: isn't it possible that *compass* here means *encompass*, like it says in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A now old-fashioned meaning of 'compass' (as a transitive verb) is to 'bring about or achieve' something. In Chapter XX the Invisible Man told Kemp that he had financed his invisibility experiments by stealing money from his own father. The money was not his father's; its loss caused his ruin and he shot himself.  The Invisible Man says that he had become apathetic and could not recover the enthusiasm and passion that he had during his earlier experiments, and which enabled him to deliberately do something which would bring about the disgrace and ruin ('downfall') of his own father. We also know that he had no scruples about killing animals to further his experiments, and, as you may realise, the Invisible Man is more than a little mad.

> Definition of compass
>
> transitive verb
>
> 3a: BRING ABOUT, ACHIEVE

[Compass (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compass)